# Linux booting - VBR and GRUB

Tags: boot, grub, mbr

I am trying to understand the booting process in linux. Let me show what is my understanding right now about it, which of course may be wrong:

After powering on the device, BIOS is handling POST, which initializes and tests the necessary hardware. After it has finished successfully, BIOS is loading MBR to the RAM and passes control to it.

The MBR has some memory area for bootloader. In case of GRUB, that area is used for stage 1 bootloader, which is checking partition table in order to find which partition is marked as active. After determining it, it is moving on. But there is my misunderstanding. As I understand, there are few possibilities:

1. MBR is passing control to the VBR of active partition, which is loading then the secondary bootloader. For GRUB it is stage 1.5 located in MBR gap or stage 2, located somewhere,
2. MBR is passing control to the stage 1.5 bootloader, which is then passing control to stage 2 bootloader,
3. MBR is passing control directly to the stage 2 bootloader.

What decides which of these steps is taken? When do we need to split bootloader for stage 1.5 and stage 2, when do we need VBR etc.? Is it all dependent on distro? As I understand, the stage 1.5 is used just for loading driver of filesystem, which allows stage 2 to use files.

Are the all transitions between BIOS and MBR, MBR and VBR, VBR and stage1.5 etc. handled by chain loading?

Comment: Systems since 2012 use UEFI and an ESP - efi system partition for booting. The MBR was for older BIOS installs. Microsoft required vendors to install Windows 8 in UEFI with gpt partitioning with release of Windows 8.